# Keeping track of Eclipse task list in git file

Tags: eclipse, git, mylyn

I am trying to make make a task list for one of my projects. The project is in a git repository and I work on it from various different computers. What I want is to store all my tasks in my git repo, so that wherever I use Eclipse, I can see my tasks.

The Mylyn task list doesn't seem to offer a seamless solution to read and write my tasks in my git repo. Have you got any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the path where Mylyn saves its files to something inside your workspace. Then you should be able to manage the files with git just like everything else. I don't know about the multi user support of this approach though.

[image: Mylyn preferences]

Answer (score 0):

git can track only files so you need to import/export your tasks and store it in file in your repo.

Comment: So doing export and imports each the time I make a change is as good as it gets?